# Postman Status : 415 unsupported media type while accessing POST request web service

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs

I have created one post request method like this:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/order")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getUserInfo(Order inputOrder){

        System.out.println("Customer Name :"+inputOrder.getCustomer());
        System.out.println("Total Amt : "+inputOrder.getAmount());
        System.out.println("Customer Address: "+inputOrder.getAddress());

        return Response.status(200).entity("Your order is in-progress").build();
    }
```

I checked the web service using POSTMAN.

Postman gives following error:415 Unsupported Media Type

Code for Order Model:

```
public class Order {     

private String customer;

private String address;     

private String amount;

public String getCustomer() {
    return customer;
}
public void setCustomer(String customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getAmount() {
    return amount;
}
public void setAmount(String amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}

}
```

[image]
[image]
Simple Get request is working with Postman. My Get request method :

```
  @GET
  @Path("/{name}")
  public Response getMessage(@PathParam("name") String name)
  {
    String outMsg = "Hello " + name + "!";
    return Response.status(200).entity(outMsg).build();
  }
```

Comment: Post the KymAddressModel class as well.

Comment: Do you have a [JSON provider](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json)?

Comment: yes i have included jason jar file also